# Unable to set column names after a group by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I have ran a pymongo query and pulled this information into a pandas dataframe called "crime". I'm now trying to group by 'Primary Type' and "Year' and count the records and display the count as a header in the dataframe for plotting. I've tried the following but I can't get the heading for count to appear.

```
new = crime.drop('_id', axis=1)
g = crime.drop('Date', axis=1)
g = new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year'])
g.columns = ['Count', 'Primary Type', 'Year']
```

I've also tried:

```
g = new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year']).
['_id']count().reset_index(name="Count")


File "<ipython-input-100-5d65646da11c>", line 3
g = new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year']).
['_id']count().reset_index(name="Count")
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid sy
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need because very long code `()` before and after or use `\` in the ends:

```
g = (new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year'])['_id']
        .count()
        .reset_index(name="Count")
        .reindex(columns=['Count', 'Primary Type', 'Year']))

g = new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year'])['_id'] \
       .count()  \
       .reset_index(name="Count") \
       .reindex(columns=['Count', 'Primary Type', 'Year'])
```

Also `drop` code is omited and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) was added for change columns names ordering.

Sample:

```
new = pd.DataFrame({'Primary Type':list('aaabbb'),
                   'Year':[2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002],
                   '_id':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'Date':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (new)
   Date Primary Type  Year  _id
0     1            a  2001    7
1     3            a  2001    8
2     5            a  2002    9
3     7            b  2002    4
4     1            b  2002    2
5     0            b  2002    3

g = (new.groupby(['Primary Type', 'Year'])['_id']
        .count()
        .reset_index(name="Count")
        .reindex(columns=['Count', 'Primary Type', 'Year']))
print (g)
   Count Primary Type  Year
0      2            a  2001
1      1            a  2002
2      3            b  2002
```